# Functions returning issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

I'm currently writing a code that asks the user for an integer and calculates the number of divisors the integer has. I've finished the code but am stuck on the "returning part".
This is what I've got so far:

```
def findDivisors(number):
    decrease = number
    count = 0
    while ( decrease >= 1):
        if ( number%decrease == 0 ):
            count=count+1
    decrease=decrease-1

def main(count):
    number = int(input("Please enter a positive integer : "))
    print(count)

main()
```

I've tried returning both "number" and "count" but can't seem to make it work.
Any suggestions ? 
BTW, I'm using Python 3.3.1

Comment: Your call to main on the bottom line does not match any previously defined functions. Your findDivisors() function will go into an infinite loop because you decremented the decrease varaible not within the while loop; so for any numbers greater than 0, an infinite loop will occur. For other fixes, refer to the first answer by @Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need `return count` at the end of the function `findDivisors()`.
2. The indentation in `findDivisors()` appears to be incorrect (`decrease=decrease-1` should be indented as much as the first line of the `if` statement.
3. I don't see any reason why you would want `count` as a parameter to the `main()` function, especially when you are calling `main()` without any parameters.
4. There is no evidence from the code that you've shown that you are actually calling the function `findDivisors()`. I'd suggest replacing the `print` call with `print(findDivisors(number))`.